# How do I get the last digit (15th luhn check digit) for a given 14 digit number with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a 14 digit number, 86162200359545 I have to append the luhn digit to make it complete. How do I get the digit with sql server. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "how do you get it".  Are you looking for how to *read* it?  Then I'd think the T-SQL [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) command should do the trick.  But your question in whole seems o indicate you don't want to read it, you want to append to the string, or maybe calculate the check digit...

Comment: You want to calculate the check-sums for a Luhn algorithm? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Comment: I understand the luhn algorithm, I want to get the last check digit for the given number and append to the number, in this case its 0 so what i desire in my final output is 861622003595450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append a single digit simply multiply by ten and add

```
DECLARE @n BIGINT = 86162200359545 
DECLARE @d INT = 0

SELECT @n * 10 + @d
```

to calculate the check digit, use a numbers table to split the string into its digits, and apply the calculation

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (id VARCHAR(15))

INSERT INTO @data (id)
VALUES ('7992739871')

SELECT luhn_id = CAST(id AS BIGINT) * 10 + d
FROM (
    SELECT id, d = SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN f > 9 THEN (f / 10) + ((f * 1.0 / 10 - 1) * 10) ELSE f END AS INT)) * 9 % 10
    FROM (
        SELECT id, f = CAST(SUBSTRING(id, n, 1) AS INT) * CASE WHEN n % 2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
        FROM @data
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP (LEN(id)) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
            FROM (SELECT 1 a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) x
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 b UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) y
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 c UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) z
        ) numbers
    ) t
    GROUP BY id
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to do it would be something like :
number = number * 10 + luhn

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your query properly. See if below code helps you.

```
DECLARE @ChkDidgit INT = 0;
DECLARE @AuctualNum BIGINT = 86162200359545;


SELECT CAST((CAST(@AuctualNum AS VARCHAR) + CAST(@ChkDidgitAS VARCHAR)) AS BIGINT)
```